# How do I get my (external) class object to store values in my current class collection?

Tags: java, generics

I have been able to create an object to call a method from a separate class, but I haven't figured out how to use those set/get methods and store them in my current class collection. Help?

Right now, it's storing strings in my class object. I know this is obviously not how it should look but I don't know how to format a proper statement that stores this logic into my foodList ArrayList.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GenericStackApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This creates a new ArrayList with String type elements
        ArrayList<String> foodList = new ArrayList<>();

        // This creates an object, to enable the program to use the methods
            // from the other Stack class and keeping this code cleaner
        Stack stack = new Stack();

        // This calls the addElement method from the Stack class, and passes
            // a the String as an argument. I obviously have no issue using
            // this external method, the issue for me was actually assigning
            // the values of each added element to the existing foodList 
            // ArrayList I initially created.
        stack.addElement("Apples");
        stack.addElement("Oranges");
        stack.addElement("Bananas");

        // This is the code that would be used to display each element, had
            // they been added correctly to the foodList ArrayList. Otherwise,
            // this is just meaningless code for now.
        for (String fruit : foodList) {
            System.out.println(foodList);
        }

        // This provides the actual size of the ArrayList. What's strange to me
            // is notice the getSize method is called and returns the size of the
            // linkedList
        System.out.println("The stack contains " + stack.getSize() + " items.");

        // This is code that would have grabbed a peek into the last element
            // of the foodList, had they been added to this collection correctly
        stack.lastElement();
        for (String fruit : foodList) {
                System.out.println(foodList);
            }

        System.out.println("The stack contains " + stack.getSize() + " items.");

        // This removes the last element in the list, one by one. The console
            // output provides a String summarizing each action.
        stack.removeElement();
            System.out.println(foodList + " has been removed.");
        stack.removeElement();
            System.out.println(foodList + " has been removed.");
        stack.removeElement();
            System.out.println(foodList + " has been removed.");

        System.out.println("The stack contains " + stack.getSize() + " items.");

    }
}
```

I expect for the console to output the elements I've added and removed.

Comment: Why not use `foodList.add("Apples")` ?

Comment: I can use those methods by default and it works perfect, the issue for me is using the methods that belong in the Stack class that I am having trouble with.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments, this is unreadable.

Comment: Why do you need the `foodList` collection? can't you just use the stack by itself?

Comment: absolutely! it's a requirement for my assignment though :)